# SQL Query to display Calculated fields on a year, monthly basis

Tags: postgresql

I need help writing this SQL query (PostgresSQL) to display results in the form below:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    State          | Jan '17 | Feb '17 | Mar '17 | Apr '17 | May '17  ... Dec '18
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Principal Outs.    |700,839  |923,000  |953,000  |6532,293 | 789,000 ...      913,212   
Disbursal Amount   |23,000   |25,000   |23,992   | 23,627  | 25,374 ...      23,209 
Interest           |113,000  |235,000  |293,992  |322,627  |323,374 ...      267,209
```

There are multiple tables but I would be okay joining them.

Comment: Research postgresql pivot, post your query if you get stuck together with sample data from all your tables (as text in the question).

Comment: So how does your input data look like?

Comment: Input data is simply summed up on the table list. Principal Outs, Interest, Disbursal Amounts are columns in different tables. @a_horse_with_no_name